# Playwright button click works unpredictably

Tags: asp.net, playwright, playwright-dotnet

I have at least three options to click on a button:

1. `await page.Locator("button", new() { HasText = "Создать" }).ClickAsync();`
2. `await page.GetByRole(AriaRole.Button, new() { Name = "Создать" }).ClickAsync();`
3. `await page.GetByText("Создать") .ClickAsync();`

The page on which I do this, based on my practical observations, can give 2 options for this button in the HTML markup:

1. selector: `#app-content > div > div > div._1hAP9 > div > div.f\\+e\\+A > button`
   xpath: `/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/button`
2. selector: `#app-content > div > div > div._1hAP9 > div > div > button`
   xpath: `/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[7]/div/div/button`

At the same time, from the developer console `document.querySelector` will find the button in both paths for both HTML variants. But from playwright, they sometimes work, sometimes they don't. At the same time, the execution continues to go further through the commands, as if the click was made, although, in fact, it does not occur (I observed the behaviour of the browser with the `headless=false` parameter).

Also, the `Force = true` parameter sometimes affects the behaviour of buttons, and sometimes nothing changes, the code continues to go further and crashes on the timeout of a component that has not yet appeared, because the button has not been pressed.

How can I make it so that this button is finally clicked ALWAYS?

Comment: Sounds like a bug, either in Playwright your app which you are testing. I recommend filing an issue on GitHub with a reproduction.

Comment: `although, in fact, it does not occur` how did you determine that? Are you sure the problem isn't the click handler, or whatever the page does after the click? `crashes on the timeout of a component that has not yet appeared, because the button has not been pressed` how *is* that component displayed?

Comment: @panagiotis-kanavos the page gets to the point where the button should be clicked and nothing else happens. After the timeout falls on pressing the next button, which has not yet appeared on the screen (the previous one was not pressed).

Comment: Post your code, don't describe it. The last comment just repeated what's in the question. Post your actual page code, including the script handler. Right now, there's very little usable information: 1) this happens only on headless mode 2) you expected something else to appear. Were you trying to open a doc viewer or print page? At the very least record a trace to see what's actually going on instead of guessing from timeouts. A full trace includes snapshots of the page and the *DOM*, along with all events, including network events and console messages.

Comment: @max-schmitt https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/26652

Comment: You can put an expect to stop moving it further if thats possible